# Passing Parameter in Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I want to pass the parameter(Command3) to a Task which is created after completing the dependent tasks (task1 and task2).

```
        Task[] tasks = { task1, task2 };
        ICommand command3 = new TestCommand3();
        Task task3 = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (setOfTasks) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task3");
        });
```

I do see the Task.Factory.StartNew and ContinueWith methods has that option and don't see parameter passing option available in ContinueWhenAll and ContinueWhenAny methods. So want to know if there is any other better workaround option available.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to avoid closing over the `command3` local variable?

Comment: i am creating a  bunch of threads dynamically and don't want get a possible situation where outer local variable altered by other threads/tasks.

Comment: You can see all the code in the method, so you can check how any of the lambdas use that variable. Because of that, I don't think what you're worrying about is an issue.

Comment: Just a passing thought: why not a `ContinueWith` off the `ContinueWhenAll`?

Comment: I have a scenario where the tasks are created dynamically from a ForEach loop for each command. It might lead to race conditions when refer a outer variable inside the task function. 

I tried wrapping with outer task, do you think any potential risk by doing so??